# completion of non-finitely generated ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, ac.commutative-algebra

Let consider $A=k[x_{1},x_{2}...]$, the polynomial ring with countably many indeterminates.

Then we can consider the completion $\hat{A}=\varprojlim_{r,l}k[x_{1},x_{2},..]/(x_{1}^{r},..x_{l}^{r},x_{l+1},x_{l+2}..)$.
In particular, it is shown in

[Is $R=k[x_1,\ldots]\to k[[x_1,\ldots]]$ a flat morphism? What about $R\to\hat{R}$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117890/is-r-kx-1-ldots-to-kx-1-ldots-a-flat-morphism-what-about-r-to-hatr)

that $\hat{A}$ is faithfully flat.

Let $\mathfrak{m}:=(x_{1},x_{2},...)$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{m}}:=ker(\hat{A}\rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m})$.

What can we say about $\hat{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}\hat{A}$, for example is it artinian?